# how to write message in header or footer of mail using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am getting a some problem in vb script. When I have parsed the file in text body and sent to all the recipients.

But I want to append some message in header part of text body. for e.g
This mail is auto generated. No need to reply.
I am using like :

objMessage.Textbody = "Auto Genereated mail"
objMessage.Textbody = file.ReadAll

here file is parsed in text body but "Auto Gnerated mail" is not comming in text body.

Any idea guys, how to write message in header or footer.
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append both 
objMessage.Textbody ="Auto Genereated mail" & file.ReadAll

Answer (score 0):

objMessage.Textbody ="Auto Genereated mail" & file.ReadAll

It's one line everyone